# Tomcat v7.0 Server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, localhost

It was working just fine, I don't know why I have that problem:
   "Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost.
   Multiple Contexts have a path of "/MajjaneApp "

[image]

Comment: right click on tomcat server in your IDE and click on **clean** and **clean tomcat directory** then try to run again. If still facing same issue, then redeploy your application and try again.

Comment: I didn't find "clean"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I found the solution on a previous article, I just deleted some  tags and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem, when You face, straight away go to "server.xml" file.
just see there is a tag :  tag is multiple times, format that particular line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and **delete the the second tag of context tag.
Why we are doing and what are the effects, please read the below descriptions for details :

Server.xml file is the heart file of tomcat Container. it is dependent file of the server. there is a single server.xml file is available for many web application project. this file starts with  tag which indicates the the tomcat container. in other words, The server.xml file is a server dependent deployment  descriptor which is used to specify server specific configurations . There is only one server.xml for each server instance.
The  Element

The  element is the most commonly used element in the server.xml file. It represents an individual Web application that is running within a defined . There is no limit to the number of contexts that can be defined within a  element. Each  definition must have a unique context path, which is defined by the path attribute. The possible attributes for the  element are described below.

Server
   ContextManager
      ... ( tomcat configuration )
   /ContextManager
/Server

Thanks,
Rakesh Kumar Gupta